# Custom Entity Id Data Type Fails on Inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, hashids

I'm trying to use sequential `INT` ids in my data layer and use the [Hashids.NET](https://hashids.org/net/) library to give me YouTube-like 'hashed' ids in my server code and UI layers. I got it to work by creating the custom `struct` shown below which resides in memory as an `Int32` and prints to `string` as a hashed id exactly as I want. I then automatically create a `ValueConverter` in `OnModelCreating` any time any data column  property uses this data type.

This ends up working flawlessly with querying objects, includes, foreign keys, etc. However, only upon trying to insert new objects, I get the error also shown below. My goal is to get Entity Framework to ignore the `HashIdentifier` value on inserts if its value is `default`. The same way it would ignore an `int` if the value is `0`. I want the database to be generating the new keys with the `IDENTITY` I set there, and then Entity Framework to use the `ValueConverter` I have set up to use the new values in the form of my `HashIdentifier`, which already works in every other case other than inserts.

```
public partial struct HashIdentifier : IEquatable<HashIdentifier>, IEquatable<int>, IComparable<HashIdentifier>, IComparable<int>
{
    private static Hashids _hashids = new("seed", 11);

    private int _value;

    public int Value => _value;

    public HashIdentifier(in int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _hashids.Encode(Value);
    }

    public static HashIdentifier Parse(in string value)
    {
        if (TryParse(value, out HashIdentifier _result))
            return _result;
        throw new InvalidIdentifierException(value);
    }

    public static bool TryParse(in string value, out HashIdentifier result)
    {
        int[] _decode = _hashids.Decode(value);

        if (_decode.Length == 0)
        {
            result = default;
            return false;
        }
        result = new(_decode[0]);
        return true;
    }

    public int CompareTo(HashIdentifier other)
    {
        return CompareTo(other.Value);
    }

    public int CompareTo(int other)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case int _a: return Equals(_a);
            case HashIdentifier _a: return Equals(_a);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(int other)
    {
        return other == Value;
    }

    public bool Equals(HashIdentifier other)
    {
        return other.Value == Value;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(int left, HashIdentifier right)
    {
        return right.Equals(left);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(int left, HashIdentifier right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    public static explicit operator int(HashIdentifier value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator HashIdentifier(int value)
    {
        return new(value);
    }
}
```

The error I get on inserts:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TestTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

The value of the `HashIdentifier` at the time of the insert was effectively `0`. And it does call into the `ValueConverter` right before hitting the exception. So why does it think I am setting an explicit value?

#### This is not a duplicate

I've already searched the internet and StackOverflow for solutions and I haven't found one. I am *not* looking for a way to use `IDENTITY_INSERT`. Please understand my issue carefully. I want Entity Framework to work as it did before I switched my keys to use custom structs.

My table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

#### Update

This appears to be a known issue according to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations)

> Currently key properties with conversions cannot use generated key values. Vote for [GitHub issue #11597](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11597) to have this limitation removed.

Comment: please provide a create script of the db table concerned

Comment: @Jazb I updated the question with the SQL script

Comment: that answers the question then - you have the ID set as being minted on the db, so you are unable to set the ID value in code and save.

Comment: If your entities are going to be defined with a Type of HashIdentifer then EF should be fine with that with an underlying Int32 data type on the DB, however you should *not* be attributing the Id column as an Identity column.. You don't want IDENTITY(1,1) in the schema if client-side code is going to be responsible for populating this value for new records.

Comment: I am ***not*** trying to set the ID value in the code. As I wrote in the question, "The value of the HashIdentifier at the time of the insert was effectively 0". And "I want entity framework to work as it did before I switched my keys to use custom structs", and the ***main*** question in my post: "So why does it think I am setting an explicit value?"

Comment: I thought if the id value is `0` (default value), then it assumes it is not being set explicity? If this is not the case, how would I tell my `HashIdentifier` struct to act as though it is empty, and that it needs the db to increment a new id value?

Comment: from what i understand in your very 1st sentence " I'm trying to use sequential INT ids in my data layer and use the Hashids.NET library to give me YouTube-like 'hashed' ids in my server code and UI layers" -  I'd say these two things a re mutually exclusive - you can't have it both ways.

Comment: @Jazb I beg to differ. This is the entire point of Hashids.NET. And I didn't come up with this concept on my own, I was inspired by Nick Chapsas on YouTube https://youtu.be/tSuwe7FowzE

Comment: The database is expecting to generate an ID itself (1,2,3,4,5...). Looks like you are expecting EF to generate the ID and write it to the DB. You can't have *that* both ways. Declare your PK as normal INT with no auto increment/identity facility; you've told EF it is responsible for generating keys, not the db. You can't have both systems expecting to generate the ID

Comment: @CaiusJard - yes that is what my poor attempt was trying to say!

Comment: *that it needs the db to increment a new id value?* the client doesn't tell the db to increment a new value by any means; the db always increments the value and does not accept instructions to insert explicit values generated by client. It doesn't work like e.g. "if I send 0 then the db makes a new id else if I send 1234 then the db uses that" - you either declare column as identity and it's 100% db job or you declare integer and it's your job. I personally wouldn't make it my job; I'd set identity, leave the db to make the PK and have a unique other column that was my YouTube style hash key

Comment: I also watched that video by Nick - he used a Guid ID (generated via code) but displayed a hash (shortend length version of the id) in the UI.  the package did the translation both ways. The usecase you have (using it with an INT) seems a little unusual to me - but no doubt there' a valid purpose.

Comment: @CaiusJard So is there no way to mock the behavior of an `int` with another `struct` like this? From my understanding, `int` is never empty, and default value will be `0`, so `0` is *always* sent from entity framework on a new entity, or somehow it decides to ignore it. How do I get entity framework to *ignore* my `struct` if it's value is default?

Comment: @CaiusJard You've also said *"you've told EF it is responsible for generating keys"*, where and how have I told EF to generate the keys? This is exactly what I am trying to *not do*.

Comment: I don't know; it's doing it because youre getting the "cannot insert an identity when identity insert is off" message; you get that when (something other than sqlserver) tries to insert a value into a column that has an identity specified. You haven't posted any code that shows a particular EF key configuration, but I suspect you may find you  answer in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: @CaiusJard Welp. There it is, `Currently key properties with conversions cannot use generated key values. Vote for GitHub issue #11597 to have this limitation removed.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Also I found this, which is my exact issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12135

Comment: Ah,, bummer.. So about that "make an INT PK IDENTITY column for the primary key, and then have another unique, indexed column that is your youtube hash.." thing :)

Comment: I'm going to try giving `[Key]` attribute to the private backing field as an `int`, and see if that works

Comment: Interestingly, as of 6 hours ago, this issue looks like it has a potential fix submitted for review. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/27759